# Curing strength of celery powder vs pink salt

Tags: curing

I would like to ask the differences in curing strength of celery powder vs pink salt when used in a salt mixure. Should I use more or less celery powder when substituting it for pink salt?

Comment: What makes you think that celery powder is helpful for curing?

Comment: @Stephie, celery powder is high in nitrates. Used in many products, where they want the marketing to say "no nitrates added" and the color and taste of nitrates. No idea if it is enough to actually cure something. _they ... use celery powder and celery juice (note the asterisk on the label above) as their nitrate source (celery is loaded with nitrate) and are therefore are allowed to say no nitrites added._ http://ruhlman.com/2011/05/the-no-nitrites-added-hoax/

Comment: I used to use celery juice via my hurom juicer. But then I got my hands on some celery powder and tried them out yesterday. Will check progress by next Monday.